# FLEX compile error in unix (Command failed for target `.bootstrap')

Tags: compiler-construction, flex-lexer, bootstrapping

I would like to compile flex in unix but return to me as command failed to target '.bootstrap'
I could not understand this error. is there any idea  about this problem?

*** Error code 2
make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `.bootstrap'

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you got the most recent version of `flex` from CVS and then attempted to build it. If that's the case, you should read the file `README.cvs` at the top level of the source code tree, which has a long list of prerequisites. One of those is:

> flex (latest beta release);  for bootstrap of scan.l

In other words, if you want to build `flex` from CVS, you first need to install the latest beta release because the flex build requires an existing binary of a recent version of flex in order to generate flex's own scanner.

The release tarball includes a pregenerated scanner, so you can build the package without an existing flex binary.

Comment: How can I download lates beta release for bootstrap error.

Comment: @yusahin: The latest version (and older ones) is available on sourceforge: http://sourceforge.net/projects/flex/files/ . Download the latest one, compile it, and use that to bootstrap the trunk. If you really feel you need to do that; you may well be better off just using the lastest version (currently 2.5.39)